# How to implement lodash-like shallow comparison of objects?

Tags: javascript, lodash

[`_.find(collection, [predicate=_.identity], [fromIndex=0])`](https://lodash.com/docs#find) uses `predicate=_.identity` to match objects in a collection, e.g.

```
> _.find([{a: 'A', n: 0}, {a: 'A', n: 0}], {a: 'A'})
< Object {a: "A", n: 0}
```

What is the actual function used to perform a comparison?

e.g. I want to check if specific object (e.g. `{a: 'A', n: 0}`) matches my predicate `{a: 'A'}`.

A simple workaround is creating an auxiliary array and using it to write a condition, e.g. `!!_.find([{a: 'A', n: 0}], {a: 'A'})`. Though there mush a function to perform anequivalent comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are looking for a way to

> check if specific object (e.g. {a: 'A', n: 0}) matches my predicate {a: 'A'}

maybe you can use lodash's `_.isMatch` [method](https://lodash.com/docs#isMatch).

```
> _.isMatch({a: 'A', n: 0}, {a: 'A'})
true
```

Comment: I knew I am overlooking something. Thank you